# Is it correct to say "what weather is supposed to be tonight?"

Tags: expressions, word-order, definite-article

Is it correct to say

> "What weather **is** supposed to be tonight?"

Or I have to say

> "What **is** the weather supposed to be tonight?"

I want to use **"supposed to be"** as a phrasal verb.

Comment: _What weather is supposed to be tonight?_ is not idiomatic and would never be heard from a native English speaker. Your second sentence is fine, or even better: _"What's the weather going to be like tonight?"_

Answer (score 2):

it would be correct to say

"What is the weather supposed to be tonight?"

also, "What will the weather be tonight?" would be about equivalent.

Comment: Often in colloquial American English  speaking (unsure about other dialects) "What is" will be shortened to "What's" 

"What's the weather supposed to be tonight?"